# Is there a way to convert a map image layer to a .png/.jpeg file?

Tags: mapping, amazon-web-services

I am trying to host a map image layer (ArcGIS map service file) on an Amazon Web Service map. I want to reference this in an Amazon Location Services app that I'm creating for my coworkers. My theory in converting this to a .png file is because i saw a tutorial previously and I want to replicate this for this purpose. I realize that referencing a Map image layer in AWS location services is difficult and I was not able to have success so far. Is there any way to achieve this or a hack around that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your root query, one way I can suggest is to create a layout and export it as a PNG file.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/sharing/overview/png-export.htm

Now, getting back to using a map service from ArcGIS Server into AWS LS is likely possible.

Here's how you can work with map services alongside AWS Location Service:

Obtain API Keys or Credentials: Sign up for an account with your chosen map service provider and obtain API keys or credentials required to access their map services.

Integrate with AWS Location Service: Use the APIs and SDKs provided by AWS Location Service to retrieve geospatial data and perform location-based operations, such as geocoding, routing, and geofencing. When you need to visualize this data on a map, make API requests to your chosen map service provider's APIs using the obtained credentials.

Display Maps in Your Application: Use the map service provider's APIs and SDKs to display maps within your application's user interface. You can customize the appearance of the maps, add markers, overlays, and layers, and enable user interaction features such as zooming and panning.

https://mediaspace.esri.com/media/t/1_x4xyhapi

Also try connecting with ESRI and AWS community for confirming if this is even a possibility.

Comment: ok will give it a shot. thank you!

Comment: Turns out this an arcgis image service with scale dependencies. I don't think a static .png file will do the trick.